# GWT Upload fails to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, memcached, gwtupload

I want to provide a file upload to Google App Engine with the "GWT Upload" (https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/). During the upload I get an error. As `UploadAction` servlet I use the build in: `gwtupload.server.gae.AppEngineUploadAction`

The servlet is configured in the web.xml in the following way:

```
<context-param>
    <!-- max size of the upload request -->
    <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
    <param-value>3145728</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <!-- Useful in development mode to slow down the uploads in fast networks. 
        Put the number of milliseconds to sleep in each block received in the server. 
        false or 0, means don't use slow uploads -->
    <param-name>slowUploads</param-name>
    <param-value>200</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- This is the default servlet, it puts files in session -->
    <servlet-class>gwtupload.server.gae.AppEngineUploadAction</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gupld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

During upload the progress bar progresses some percentages and then shows the following error:

[image: error message]

But there are no more details in the logs.

The error message shows the class `gwtupload.server.gae.MemCacheFileItemFactory$CacheableFileItem` with the method `setHeader()`. That's strange because I can't find the method in that class. What's happening here?

**Edit:**
This is basically all the custom code i use. On the server side i use the build in `gwtupload.server.gae.AppEngineUploadAction` servlet.

```
package com.uploadtest.client;

import gwtupload.client.IUploadStatus.Status;
import gwtupload.client.IUploader;
import gwtupload.client.IUploader.UploadedInfo;
import gwtupload.client.MultiUploader;
import gwtupload.client.PreloadedImage;
import gwtupload.client.PreloadedImage.OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class GWTUploadTest2 implements EntryPoint {


    // A panel where the thumbnails of uploaded images will be shown
    private FlowPanel panelImages = new FlowPanel();

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // Attach the image viewer to the document
        RootPanel.get("thumbnails").add(panelImages);

        // Create a new uploader panel and attach it to the document
        MultiUploader defaultUploader = new MultiUploader();
        RootPanel.get("default").add(defaultUploader);

        // Add a finish handler which will load the image once the upload finishes
        defaultUploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(onFinishUploaderHandler);
    }

    // Load the image in the document and in the case of success attach it to the viewer
    private IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandler = new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
        public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
            if (uploader.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS) {

                new PreloadedImage(uploader.fileUrl(), showImage);

                // The server sends useful information to the client by default
                UploadedInfo info = uploader.getServerInfo();
                System.out.println("File name " + info.name);
                System.out.println("File content-type " + info.ctype);
                System.out.println("File size " + info.size);

                // You can send any customized message and parse it 
                System.out.println("Server message " + info.message);
            }
        }
    };

    // Attach an image to the pictures viewer
    private OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler showImage = new OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler() {
        public void onLoad(PreloadedImage image) {
            image.setWidth("75px");
            panelImages.add(image);
        }
    };

}
```

In addition to that i added the following jars to my clath path:

- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- gwtupload-gae-0.6.6.jar
- gwtupload-0.6.6.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
- commons-io-2.4.jar

Also zipped my whole sample project and uploaded it here:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=60B826E451F52B4D!118&authkey=!ALa1n2mL2sRR0wU

**Edit 2:**

Like Manolo pointed out: I was using "commons-fileupload-1.3.jar" instead of "commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar". Changing the jar fixed my problem!

Comment: could you share your project or a small one with the issue somehow, so I can install it and figure out what is happening?

Comment: another question, does it fail in dev mode as well, or just in prod gae servers?

Comment: @Manolo: I uploaded the sample project here: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=60B826E451F52B4D!118&authkey=!ALa1n2mL2sRR0wU

Comment: @Manolo: It fails in dev mode as well on the gae servers with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the version of the commons-fileupload you are using, change it to the version 1.2.1, which is the one pointed in the [gwtupload documentation](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted).

It should work with 1.2.2 as well, but to use 1.3 requires new methods (setHeaders) which are not in the UploadListeners provided with gwtupload.

You should change in your project the target java (JDK compliance) to 1.6, since it is the last one supported in GWT to avoid problems, although it runs in 1.7.